# How to better setting up JVM encoding properties to UTF-8

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, encoding, jvm

When I trying package project with Maven, I receive this

```
...  
-------------------------------------------------------
   T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
...
    
        2017-09-23 14:00:11.447 ERROR 11468 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.FileEncodingApplicationListener  : System property 'file.encoding' is currently 'Cp1252'. It should be 'UTF-8' (as defined in 'spring.mandatoryFileEncoding').
        2017-09-23 14:00:11.464 ERROR 11468 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.FileEncodingApplicationListener  : Environment variable LANG is 'null'. You could use a locale setting that matches encoding='UTF-8'.
        2017-09-23 14:00:11.464 ERROR 11468 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.FileEncodingApplicationListener  : Environment variable LC_ALL is 'null'. You could use a locale setting that matches encoding='UTF-8'.
        2017-09-23 14:00:11.802 ERROR 11468 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
        
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Java Virtual Machine has not been configured to use the desired default character encoding (UTF-8).
```

It can be fixed like: add Environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTION` = `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"`but it don't works.

[Environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLVCo.png)

In IntelliJ Idea Settings everything is set to UTF-8.

aplication.properties

```
spring.mandatory-file-encoding=UTF-8
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Using Windows 10.

Comment: is any of these properties used in `maven-compiler-plugin`?

Comment: No they are not used by maven-compiler-plugin. `java.version` is used by spring-boot but only if you use the spring boot parent. Otherwise it does not work that way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can encode the source encoding and output encoding by passing runtime arguments to command as follows:

```
mvn -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dproject.reporting.outputEncoding=UTF-8 clean deploy
```

Or by adding line in `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <redis.version>1.3.5.RELEASE</redis.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Setting the encoding via command line `project.build.sourceEncoding` is already done via the properties via properties area in pom file..no need to do that another time on command line. The most important one is to set the file-encoding...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try specifying it as a command line argument, e.g.:

```
java -Dfile-encoding=UTF-8 -jar yourfile.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn test -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Can you explain the answer?