# Maven install has wrong platform encoding

Tags: java, maven, encoding, character-encoding

Whenever i do a mvn -version i get the following response

```
Apache Maven 3.9.1 (2e178502fcdbffc201671fb2537d0cb4b4cc58f8)
Maven home: /Users/xxxxx/apache-maven-3.9.1
Java version: 11.0.18, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.0.18/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_NL, platform encoding: US-ASCII
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.2.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

It says that the platform encoding is US-ASCII but i want it to be UTF-8.

When i'm trying to run my unit test i get the following stacktrace.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Java Virtual Machine has not been configured to use the desired default character encoding (UTF-8).
        at org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(FileEncodingApplicationListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(FileEncodingApplicationListener.java:48)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:148)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
        ... 72 more
```

At first i thought that i messed something up in the pom.xml. but nothing seams wrong there. i've tried to follow the solution given in [How to configure encoding in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017695/how-to-configure-encoding-in-maven)

But nothing seems to change the encoding. When i just run the mvn -version in a fresh terminal i also get the same result so my guess is that it has nothing to do with spring.

But if it's not a spring config, then where do i change the platform encoding to UTF-8 so i can start to run my tests.

I've also tried everything from this question [How to better setting up JVM encoding properties to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379215/how-to-better-setting-up-jvm-encoding-properties-to-utf-8)

Also with no succes.

Comment: I would check this: `galStateException: The Java Virtual Machine has not been configured to use the desired default character encoding (UTF-8)` ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to better setting up JVM encoding properties to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379215/how-to-better-setting-up-jvm-encoding-properties-to-utf-8)

Comment: @skomisa thnx for the response but all of the suggestions and solutions from that link don't change anything in my case. I already had the 

```
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

In my pom. When i use the mvn -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dproject.reporting.outputEncoding=UTF-8 clean deploy command i still get the same errors

Comment: @MitchelAbrahams OK, fair enough, I have retracted my close vote.